# Better Bounty System for Other People's Questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

After issuing my first bounty on Stack Overflow, I think there is some rethinking that needs to be done on how this system works.

If you issue any bounty on Stack Overflow, those rep points are gone from you forever. The [thinking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) is that you are paying to gain extra attention for *your* issue. **This model makes sense for your own questions but not for someone else's questions.**

The current bounty system for other people's questions is flawed because it **does not incentivize members to reexamine older questions that need better answers**. In fact, it actively *penalizes* those actions by charging you rep points to do so - completely the opposite of the behavior we want to encourage.

What I would like to propose is a **different set of rules** for putting a bounty on someone *else's* question:

- When a community member puts a bounty on someone else's question, they have judged a question to be insufficiently answered and in need of a better/canonical answer. This is an action that would, theoretically, benefit all of S.O (but not necessarily).
- The bounty should be held in escrow by S.O. during the bounty period.
- If someone leaves a *subjectively* better answer (new answer has LESS upvotes than currently accepted answer), the bounty offerer can reward it to answerer just like now. The rep is then transferred from the escrow to the answerer. Offerer receives nothing in this scenario, same as now.
- If someone leaves an *objectively* better answer (new answer is more than 10 upvotes better than old answer), bounty offerer's offer is matched by S.O. (like a PBS fundraising drive). Both the answerer and offerer are given the now doubled-bounty. This would incentivize community-beneficial bounties, better matching the risk/reward ratio for putting a bounty on someone else's question.
- If no one answer is judged to be a better answer by the offerer, the rep points should automatically go back to offerer. This would encourage more people to put bounties on insufficiently answered questions because they could get a rebate if no better information is added by the community.

This is just a proposal but I think it would go a long way to reforming what is a broken process for putting bounties on other people's questions.

Comment: You seem to be describing a situation where *you* don't personally benefit from a better answer to the question you're bountying. That scenario exists, I'm sure - but that wasn't really the primary intent of allowing 3rd-party bounties. I'd like to see more thought put into identifying scenarios where this need exists and is being underserved right now; I'm not convinced that answer heuristics are the proper way to identify it. Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817/how-do-we-encourage-edits-to-obsolete-out-of-date-answers

Comment: I'm not sure how to judge the whole proposal but the last bullet about the *rebate* is not something I fancy. A bounty should still be an investment were you run the risk of losing the *money*...

Comment: so... for me, bounties have always been like newspaper ads. You pay for the AD, not for who answers it. If there's a question in which you're not involved enough to give a bounty unless it's rebated... then it's not something you should bounty.

Comment: The second to last bullet point seems ripe for gaming. If a group of people got together and found a question without an answer, one of them offered the largest bounty they could, one of them answers, the rest upvote it, all of a sudden the answerer gets a boatload of rep, and their answer may not even be very good. They could then go on to repeat the process, cycling between users indefinitely.

Comment: *it does not incentivize members to reexamine older questions that need better answers* - How does a new bounty not do this? People will still see that someone's offering a bounty of X rep for a new answer. How is that not incentive?

Comment: @rene - if a bounty is an investment beyond one developer, why wouldn't a rebate make sense? The 'money' is supposed to be for the community benefit - it would be like putting up a reward to clean a street median and then nobody showed up on the community service day.

Comment: @Shog9 I'd be totally on board spending a lot of rep on making questions better that I personally don't have an interest in. That there's very few opportunities to do that doesn't have that many *technical* reasons than it has *cultural* ones, though - there's no  bat signal with which to find questions and askers in need, no one ever asks for folks to put up a bounty, etc. There's some pointers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137693/how-do-i-invest-a-bounty-for-the-greater-good) but neither approach is really intuitive

Comment: @shog9 - interesting idea behind obsolete answer.

Answer (score 2):

> This is just a proposal but I think it would go a long way to reforming what is a broken process for putting bounties on other people's questions.

It's hard to see how the bounty system is "broken" in the case you describe.

There's no need to "sufficiently answer" a question that nobody cares about. Conversely, if someone (the author or someone else) cares enough to put a bounty on a question, then it'll get extra attention and often at least a few answers.

Putting a bounty on a question that nobody cares about hurts the site by taking attention away from questions that people *do* care about.

Comment: Why assume a bountied question is not cared about? The more common use case I see is obscure questions that get buried by the poor discovery mechanisms in S.O. It took me about 30 seconds of searching the bounty queue to find a great example of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133987/cannot-open-ssl-key-file-in-node-server-enoent. Should we penalize this behavior?

Comment: I assume the opposite: that a bounty is an indication that someone *does* care about the question enough to offer a bit of their own rep. It's the unbountied, unanswered,  obscure questions that, by definition, nobody cares about. If the discovery system on SO needs improvement, that's a different topic; the bounty system isn't the right answer for that.

Comment: A priori, all valid questions get attention they deserve and accurate, timely answers are delivered. In the real world that doesn't happen, so we have bounties to raise attention. There is no implicit value judgment on an unanswered question - good and bad fall through the cracks. 3rd party bounties only reason for being is to raise attention to questions that get buried yet still have merit for a wide audience.

Comment: No, a 3rd party bounty is for when *you* want an answer (or a *better* answer) to a question that someone has already asked. There's no reason to offer a bounty on a question in which *you* are not interested, and you should not. There's no difference between offering a bounty on your own question and offering one on someone else's. If a question "has merit for a wide audience" then let someone in that audience deal with it.

Comment: Maybe your whole line of thinking is right - everyone is just out for themselves on S.O. and bounties are always a selfish ask. That seems terribly wrong to me but clearly you and everyone else who weighed in on this feels similarly. That's sad to me but I guess that's how this community feels. I can tell you I answer way more questions than I ask on this site and the bounty system should reflect some degree of altruism, FWIW.

Comment: It's really more about efficiency. If you offer a bounty because you are interested in the answer, then we know that at least one person really is interested. If you offer bounties on questions that you personally don't care about, then it's very possible that nobody cares about the answer. What good is that? It's just a waste of everybody's time, and it takes attention away from questions that would actually help someone. SO is full of altruism: volunteers spend thousands of hours every day answering questions and curating the site.

Answer (score -2):

Great idea! I believe a better system for setting bounties would benefit everyone. Sometimes I will search google and find a stack overflow question with no answer. I now cannot ask this question on stack overflow because it is a duplicate. And since the question is old no one notices it or cares to answer it, especially if it is a difficult question. I also wouldn't give it a bounty because I don't have that much reputation to begin with!