# Make philanthropic bounties a real part of site culture

Tags: feature-request, bounty

With the site now well into its seventh year, there is a solid field of users with a *lot* of reputation points and nothing really to do with them except, well, amassing *even more of them.*

[image]

What if we could put those points to an actual *use* - encourage the improvement of existing questions and answers, especially canonical ones, and provide an incentive to go that extra mile of research where it's needed most?

Stack Overflow currently doesn't really provide a real outlet to do that.

Sure, there are bounties and [the altruist badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/48/altruist), but the bounty system was originally designed to encourage answers you need urgently for your *own* questions, and it shows. There is no real infrastructure around starting bounties as a "philanthropic" act - bounties you start with no interest of your own, perhaps even in tags outside your domain knowledge.

- There is no designated place for interested parties to advertise questions that could benefit from a bounty
- Apart from the Altruist badge (which is ridiculously easy to fulfill) there are no cues from the system that "sponsoring" a bounty on a question you have nothing to do with is a desired behaviour
- There is no way for users to delegate the actual *awarding* of a bounty to users who have the domain knowledge to judge a question's merits - something that would be needed when starting a philanthropic bounty in a random tag

Individual users are trying to work around this by expressing their willingness to bounty good questions ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis)) and yes, in theory there could be chat rooms taking up the role of the "nominated" tab - but without some active support from the system, it's all going to go nowhere.

Let's change this!

---

**1. Create a tab with bounty-worthy questions**

In the question tabs, next to the "bounties" button, establish a "nominated" button.

[image]

The "nominated" view is nothing but a list of questions that the community has deemed worthy of receiving a philanthropic bounty - in the hopes that someone with a lot of rep will answer the call (see step 2).

Users who feel like it, can start a bounty on any question in the list.

Users with a philanthropic interest in a certain tag can filter the list, as usual.

---

**2. Let the community nominate questions**

Any question on the site with a net score of 2 or more gets a new link:

> <kbd>Nominate for bounty</kbd>

Any user with at least, say, 1500 rep can nominate a question to be featured on the "nominated" tab. The number of these votes is very limited (say, three a day).  If a question manages to amass five of these votes, it will be featured in the "nominated" tab. Unsuccessful nomination votes (that don't amass 5 votes) age away after a month or so.

The idea is that the stewards of a specific tag - those who can recognize a hard question, or a frequent question that could use a great, canonical answer - can, by nominating questions, send up flares that say "these questions could use someone to sponsor a bounty on."

---

**3. Create badges**

Create a number of *serious* philanthropy badges - bronze, silver, and gold. The gold one could be for spending, say, 10,000 points (or more!) on philanthropic bounties.

**Tweaks and side notes**

- If you vote to nominate a question you can't benefit from the resulting bounty.
- There will be the situation of the bounty-starter not knowing which answer to give the bounty to. In that case, any comments they make in the question should be @notified to the five community users who voted to nominate it, so they can possibly provide some guidance.

This idea would emphasize a new aspect of community culture that we haven't had before, but I can't really see any serious drawbacks. The danger of abuse (like, someone trying to steal a bounty through sockpuppet voting on a spurious answer) is as great as it is currently; with five community members actively expressing their interest in a question's well-being, and being available for clarification, one could argue the danger is even smaller.

This would also enable semi-alumni like myself - people who love the site, used to be very active, and have lots of points, but no longer the time / inclination to participate much - to continue to play a positive role around the place, and even re-distribute points a bit to new generations.

Perhaps  this could even be sort of a new achievement level in the game that is Stack Overflow.

Thoughts?

Comment: I like this idea, personally. One suggestion I would make is for the rep limit for nominating- I would suggest 3k myself, since that's when you can vote to close questions, but that's just because it makes more sense to me. 1.5k could work just as well. Other than that, this looks like it covers most, if not all, points I would've brought up.

Comment: Wait! Is this secretly a clever plot to encourage Jon Skeet to lower his rep so others might actually catch up to him?

Comment: @Kendra funnily enough, I just finished adding a paragraph to pretty much that extent (the second to last one in the text)

Comment: Interesting idea, though I don't think this's going to encourage high-rep users to dump thousands of their rep into blackholes without any aim rather than charity. (looking at "There will be the situation of the bounty-starter not knowing which answer to give the bounty to")

Comment: How would this impact other sites?

Comment: @JoeW I can't see how it would, do you have something specific in mind? It would likely stay limited to SO for a long time, it's the site where the overall rep level has progressed the most

Comment: I would think that any new feature should be designed around being able to work on all sites.

Comment: @nicael yeah, a bit like the problems in foreign aid. The normal rules of bountying would continue to apply, though: the bounty would be auto-awarded to the highest voted answer, and not be awarded at all if there is none that hasn't gathered at least 2 upvotes and the bounty owner doesn't decide on one.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Bounties that are auto-awarded only give half the bounty amount.

Comment: Great idea - I was just talking about reforming how altruistic bounties work earlier in the week (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313965/better-bounty-system-for-other-peoples-questions). This is a serious deficiency in the current system.

Comment: Nominated questions, if not awarded bounties after a certain amount of time, should drop out of the nominated tab.

Comment: See also: [this effort on Mechanics](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1461/3401). Altruistic efforts don't seem to cause any real damage to sites, but can build a sense of comradery on smaller sites. Larger sites would likely benefit by encouraging experienced users to give promising users a quick lift.  I think new badges would be interesting. The nomination process, however, seems a bit on the complicated side. It seems like there's a real risk we could build the system, questions could get nominated and nobody ever bounties them. How could we avoid that?

Comment: @JonEricson - Perhaps, crowd source the bounty. Allow people to contribute smaller amounts (similar to grassroots movements) towards some sort of pool while the nomination ages. That way even lower reputation users like myself could chip in something like 5,10, 25 (which isn't as big a deal as say 50,100,250). This would create a larger pool and allow for a higher frequency of "donation", it could also mean that if multiple very high reputation users chipped in the bounty could break 500.

Comment: @JonEricson I think this would have a fairly good chance of becoming a thing - especially through the badges. If just 100 users ever get the "10,000 points spent" gold badge, we'd have a huge amount of bounties. Then there could be a separate "bounties spent" leaderboard, and the number prominently displayed in the profile - that might also alleviate fears that active philanthrophy might diminish your position on SO (and hence, your chances on future job offers, etc. etc.)

Comment: Funny enough, other than MSE, I rarely apply for a bounty on my own question.

Comment: @JonEricson re complication - the nomination system would pretty much be a copy of the close vote system, so anyone familiar with that would immediately grok this.

Comment: "If you vote to nominate a question you can't benefit from the resulting bounty." I wouldn't worry too much about this, given that you need the agreement of four other reasonably-experienced users for even the _nomination_ to succeed.

Comment: If there are bounty worth questions, then the community user could just start a bounty. SE has the license to generate rep themselfs literally :)

Comment: @juergen true, they have the printing presses. But the community aspects of having *people* award bounties would have a lot of benefits. Not least the fact that there's people having a close look which answer the bounty is awarded to. Doing good with "virtual" money can lead to waste and misuse. If you have any connections to Germany (assuming from your first name you do), [you know what I mean](http://www.rundfunkbeitrag.de/) :)

Comment: I think if we take a step back, we can see the need for a _"Requesting canonical Q&A"_ list, where users (high- or low rep) can ask for other users to help find (potentially) canonical Q&As to improve and link to from related questions.

Comment: Related: [Enhance moderation ability by encouraging excellent content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254137)

Comment: I think the core problem here is that the SO FAQ system works rather poorly, which has resulted in tags like c++-faq. Maybe instead there should be a new FAQ system, where gold badge users in a tag can vote yes/no on "should be FAQ", for any question in the tag they have a gold badge for.

Comment: Whilst I like the idea, and my comments shouldn't detract from the idea, it will further marginalise low-volume tags. It is often the case where I operate that there are not enough active people to even get questions closed. So not enough to nominate, and even if a nomination succeeds, no-one left to benefit :-) . Of course, since the tags are low-volume anyway, good answers hardly matter...

Comment: @Lundin what about tags which have no gold-badge users? Wouldn't work so well there...

Comment: @BillWoodger I can only speak for myself, but I would be *very* willing to spend a lot on bounties in low-volume tags if someone told me which questions to put them on. Perhaps a tag's top users should be able to single-handedly nominations to questions.

Comment: I added a bounty to a question of others just two times. Maybe having a list of questions to add the rep to, it would help, but still... I would add bounties to questions that I'm personally involved in, or to which I personally need an answer. Before I spend a bounty, I would first want to know whether the answer isn't already available, and for that I would need to spend quite some time on a thorough search and experimentation. I wouldn't do that just for any question.

Comment: @GolezTrol I think one of the motivations here is to add bounties to answered questions as well. If the content is solid it is positive encouragement for the answerer. Assuming it is correct of course. Sci.SE has done this a few times for what they deem to be good content.

Comment: @BillWoodger If there are no gold-badge users, it suggests that the tag doesn't have enough traffic to motivate the creation of a FAQ anyhow.

Comment: Large IT companies benefit a lot from the guys who answer a lot on SO. Why not asking large companies to exhange technology for reputation points? I don't see the benefit of spending reputation points on somebody others question. (However, generally it is a good idea to think what we can do with reputation, since after the 20k border you won't be awarded any more)

Comment: @GolezTrol How do you mean that?

Comment: Don't worry about Jon Skeet. If he gave you all of his reputation, he'll still have more reputation than you.

Comment: @hek2mgl `Large IT companies benefit a lot from the guys who answer a lot on SO` - true that, but traditionally the consensus has been that any influx of money (or valuable goods) into the ecosystem would be absolutely toxic. All the negative aspects of the system (rep whoring, sock puppeteering, etc.) would suddenly become *really serious.* Imagine if 50,000 rep could buy you something that in some countries costs four weeks' wages or more. There would be *war*.

Comment: @Lundin In a way, but also it is circular. The better content here, the more likely people who need that content will come. Of course, low-volume tags can't be "equal" in treatment here to the popular tags (and no, I don't think things can be bent to make it so). Although the site may verbally aspire to inclusion, the mechanisms (rep, badges, privs, anything) show otherwise... it's just like that. Ignore me :-)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Good point. What about a cool T-Shirt per xxxx points (or other actions)? I mean something cool, but not expensive..

Comment: @BillWoodger The only tags that really needs FAQs are the main programming/script language tags, perhaps some mainstream tool tags (popular compilers, IDEs and version control programs) and misc generic computer science tags (search/sort algorithms, floating point etc). Anyway, I guess we'll have to wait and see how the new "documentation" experiment on SO will end up, as it is supposedly going to be helpful for these kind of things.

Comment: I disagree that high-volume tags are the only ones to need FAQs (or bounty questions). But yeah, the documentation effort could be a huge step forward in this

Comment: In terms of badge rewards, I would suggest something similar to the [steward](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward) gold badge that can be received multiple times for bounties awarded to different forums.

Comment: @Pekka웃, would you still keep to the 50 - 500 range, or would you allow larger bounties?

Comment: @wnnmaw that's a good question! Haven't thought about that at all yet. I suppose *if* this actually gets implemented, it might be interesting to think about bigger bounties; however, 500 arguably ought to be big enough for even the most complex undertakings on SO.

Comment: So I guess @Pekka웃 got tired of diving into his rep and swimming around in it...

Comment: @Machavity [... and diving around in it like a porpoise!](http://www.graphixia.cssgn.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/wdus01.jpg)

Answer (score 15):

A **quick** workaround with no Stack Exchange developers actively involved:

1. Create a [philanthropy](/questions/tagged/philanthropy) tag on Meta Stack Overflow. This tag should have a wiki with a guide for nominations: posts must have 5+ or 10+, not be your own, other restrictions
2. Interested parties create questions with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)[philanthropy](/questions/tagged/philanthropy) tags to nominate Stack Overflow posts (with **links**, suggested bounty, **reasons to nominate**, **suggested improvements**).
   possible issues: there are no Stack Overflow specific tags (e.g. [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23),[sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql),...) on Meta and a search for relevant nominations could take some time.
3. Interested parties read nominations and vote for them (all nominations can be easily found on Meta Stack Overflow by [philanthropy](/questions/tagged/philanthropy) tag)
4. The meta-effect generates score for authors of the nominated question and answer if they really deserve it. (Questions with normal bounties attract many more views that most new questions. This usually results in upvotes on a question and an answer).
5. [optional] Some philanthrop sponsors a bounty. They posts an answer to nomination post and their answer gets accepted.

Sponsors would get an accepted answer in their profiles, increase their [philanthropy](/questions/tagged/philanthropy) tag score, bronze/silver/gold [philanthropy](/questions/tagged/philanthropy) badge after a time, etc.

I think this answers your offers ?1 and ?2.

If someone tries to cheat or promote their posts which does not actually have high value, those nominations will be ignored or downvoted. Like other posts, downvoted nominations will be removed automatically.

*Possible Anti-Flood measures* (flood is Kendra's term):

1] Allow only **R**/1000 [philanthropy](/questions/tagged/philanthropy) nominations per month for a user with **R** reputation (a person who has 10K+ score can suggest 10 nomination in 30 days period)

Related Meta Stack Exchange post: *[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)* (so I think it can be implemented)

2] If someone creates a nomination for their own / their friends post in hope to earn more reputation and tag score *and* if that post isn't really good the effect can be negative: the Stack Overflow post would start to attract downvotes which defeats the purpose of cheating.

---

Another quick fix for badges (offer ?3): Allow to award the [Altruist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399) multiple times (requires some Stack Exchange developers' assistance; it can be done in a batch for existing altruistic bounties).

Related post: *["Question Badge" suggestion: Philanthropist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291549/question-badge-suggestion-philanthropist)*

And now just look at the numbers:

[5852 Altruist badges = Altruist users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/222/altruist) by now

I have composed a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422403/altruists) to find bounties awarded on another person's question.

I seriously thought that maximum number of altruistic bounties from one user would be from 6 to 8. It turned out that I was wrong.

There are at least 75 users who did it 10 times or more. And [Joe Blow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294884/joe-blow?tab=bounties) has 62. He has 62, Carl! And 120 total, Carl!

A list of users who have more than 20 such bounties:

```
UserId    DisplayName            TotalBountyAmount  BountyCount  AvgBounty
  30461    Peter Hosey            20000              40           500
 871050    Madara Uchiha          13850              41           337
 707111    Ryan O'Hara             9750              24           406
 376947    Alex                    9350              28           333
 772868    false                   6700              43           155
 246568    William Jockusch        6150              21           292
1325290    Tina CG Hoehr           5550              20           277
 294884    Joe Blow                5450              62            87
 610569    alvas                   4700              53            88
   1114    Jeremy Banks            4600              39           117
 447356    Shadow Wizard           4450              34           130
   2541    Sam Hasler              4050              25           162
 409172    Jon Heller              3650              37            98
 589259    Maarten Bodewes         3000              24           125
1401975    HamZa                   2700              28            96
 728812    Michael Hunger          2200              22           100
3015232    enough rep to comment   2050              29            70
 291180    Travis Webb             2000              25            80
 298389    om-nom-nom              1950              24            81
 284795    Colonel Panic           1650              25            66
```

[Peter Hosey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30461/peter-hosey?tab=bounties) sponsored 40 uber bounties [+500]. He also has two [Altruist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/222/altruist?userid=30461) badges (together with [lock](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/222/altruist?userid=1117987), [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/222/altruist?userid=409473) and [MrDatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/222/altruist?userid=22471) who has 3).

PS: Query text

```
select
count(*)
--top 20 *
from
(
  select
    v.UserId,
    max(u.DisplayName) as DisplayName,
    sum(BountyAmount) as TotalBountyAmount,
    count(*) as BountyCount,
    avg(BountyAmount) as AvgBounty
  from
    Votes v
    join Posts p on p.Id = v.PostId
    join Users u on u.Id = v.UserId
  where
    BountyAmount > 0
    -- altruistic bounties only
    and p.OwnerUserId != v.UserId
    -- exclude Community
    and u.Id != -1
  group by UserId
  having count(*) >= 10
) U
--order by TotalBountyAmount desc
```

Comment: To be honest, there'd be only the one question, so I'm not sure of the value of the tag.  In either event, it's not a bad idea; I'd see it as a soft experiment for the functionality.

Comment: I disagree with your suggestion of just using Meta for one major reason: Once this trend catches on and more and more users want to nominate questions, Meta is going to be flooded by these questions. Most of them _will_ be people nominating their own stuff, so a lot of them will likely be poor or annoying questions.

Comment: @makoto, one question for each post nomination; yes, exactly - an quick experiment, playtest!

Comment: @Kendra:  The only way around that would be for someone to implement it with the constraints as described above, which would be *far more ideal*.  However, the likelihood of Meta becoming overrun anytime soon is slim, given that we've got so many of us keeping an eye out for that kind of crap.

Comment: @ASh: No, that'd get unwieldy.  A single post as CW with nominations would suffice as an experiment.  Anything more than that, and you're getting the scenario that Kendra fears.

Comment: @Makoto If we go with _one_ question as you suggest, as long as the answers posting the nominations are cleaned up once they've been handled, I'm far more comfortable with that. Especially as a test for the viability of the feature.

Comment: @Kendra:  That's what I was thinking.  Place into the question a proviso that once someone has decided to award an answer, that the nomination be culled.  This way, they don't show up at the very top.

Comment: @Makoto, one post which is regularly cleaned is not so attractive. i think sponsors would prefer to have accepted answers in their profile, have [philanthropy] tag score, silver/gold [philanthropy] badge, etc. i don't think it will became a flood. and [philanthropy] can have a wiki with a guide - post must have 5+ or 10+, not be your own, others ...

Comment: @ASh:  Again, this is a test.  The things you're suggesting would be better suited for the real deal, as opposed to something buried on Meta.

Comment: @ASh It would need to be one single question. People don't read tag wikis, and they _would,_ once they found out about this, post questions that don't meet the guidelines in an attempt to promote their own questions for answers. One regularly cleaned post is far easier to keep maintained, _and_ it won't get in the way of users who want no part. Even if they ignore the tag, there will be users who won't post their question with that tag and just want their post to get attention. Those mistagged questions will get in the way of other users.

Comment: @Kendra, i think sponsors would prefer to have accepted answers in their profile, have [philanthropy] tag score, silver/gold [philanthropy] badge, etc. if answers are cleared this part will not work. Bad [philanthropy] nominations should be downvoted and closed as bad questions.

Comment: And those sponsers are going to be outnumbered, most likely, by meta users who want no part in this. Those users will complain and the whole thing will get shut down. And there will be a number of bad questions, if we do it this way. Yes, they will be closed as bad, but that will take extra time. And nominations _do not_ need to stick around once they're done, so cleaning the answers once the situation has been handled is a good idea to get old nominations out of the way and keep them from popping back up. (e.g. via edits)

Comment: We _cannot_ cater to just the sponsors here. We need to make this something that isn't going to get in the way of people who don't want it, but is still going to be easy to keep clean, maintained, and _working._

Comment: @Kendra, most of all in this i don't want *a new tab* on questions page and profile page :D. and i think we need another answer here with all these thoughts and counter-argument for people to vote - what **they** want :) can you please compose and post it?

Comment: @Kendra, btw, if nomitation is deleted after being completed, meta-effect will be lost

Comment: @ASh The goal here isn't to use the meta effect, though. The point of this proposal is to get _bounties_ on those questions to a) get more attention to get them answered or, likely more rarely b) reward an amazing answer. I would bet it will mostly be used for getting answers to great, unanswered questions. (But I will consider writing up a proposal countering, but similar to, yours.)

Comment: @Kendra, i have added a paragraph about possible Anti-Flood measures

Answer (score 3):

*This is a comment that didn't fit into the comment box.*

What's the point of pushing canonical questions even further? Don't they get enough praise from search results?

And don't we have [other means](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) to improve those anyway?

[I think there are other questions that could make good use of some attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295713/can-we-blow-away-some-of-the-tumbleweeds)

I think there are certain questions that are inherently unattractive to be answered, because it takes more effort to answer them. Some of those questions often involve different technologies and their interaction. If I see a question like "*How can I use library X to connect to database Y with hardware Z with requirement A?*" then I usually do not even bother looking at it. Especially not if I don't even know half the words they are tagged with. If it's unlikely that I can answer the question, I have no motivation to interact with it in any way. "*Good luck finding somebody who can answer **that**!*"

If that statement changed to "*Wow, if somebody goes the whole nine yards to answer **that** beast of a question, props to him/her!*" Or rather "*...rep to him/her!*", then I think some questions that do not have answers now, could get one.

In order for this to work, the mentality has to change, too and I'm not sure if getting another badge will do that trick. After all, this transforms ***amassing more reputation* into *amassing more badges***.

I like the idea of bringing attention to certain questions/answers (+1), but I don't think canonical questions are those that need it most.

Comment: The question you suggest deserves a bounty, would likely need to be closed as too broad. SO is designed for quick and easy answers. There's been plenty of times that I've written a short novella as an answer, but from those experiences, I can say it's extremely difficult to write long-form answers. The longer it gets, the more unwieldy the answering UI becomes. Long and short, if it's the type of question that you skip because it requires entirely too much effort to answer, that means the user is asking a broad question or hasn't done their own sufficient research/attempt at a solution.

Answer (score -7):

Personally, I'd rather see a feature where you can nominate/vote on questions getting bounties *applied by the site*. In other words, a site like Stack Overflow, for example, would award maybe 50, 100, etc. reputation points to the accepted answer, rather than the standard 15.

The more nomination "upvotes", the higher the bounty goes, on some kind of pre-defined scale. 5 upvotes makes it 25 instead of 15; 10 upvotes makes it 50; etc.

In this way, *anyone* in the community could participate (after reaching some sort of reputation points threshold TBD), whether or not they felt like they had an excess of reputation points of their own. This could also fit pretty easily in the existing review queue infrastructure - just add a new category of posts that are nominated for bounties, and then users could review and add their support from that queue.