# Award a bounty for a good question

Tags: feature-request, bounty

As far as I know you can only award a bounty for an answer.

Sometimes I see really good questions - which I promptly vote up - but in addition would like to award them with a bounty for asking such a good question.

After all, I see many people complaining about the low quality of questions...

Maybe by adding the possibility of awarding bounties to questions we can provide an additional incentive to ask better quality questions.

Or to put it differently: If we have a bounty for rewarding genuinely good answers, why *shouldn't* there be a bounty for rewarding genuinely good original questions?

Here's an image of the bounty popup just to prove that bounties are not just for drawing attention:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

---

**NB:** I posted a follow-up question with an alternative way to encourage good questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320031/703717)

Comment: The point of a bounty is to get more attention (and therefore hopefully more/better answers), **not** *"for rewarding genuinely good answers"*. How does giving the OP more rep for a question *they've already asked* incentivise something useful?

Comment: @jonrsharpe ahem, one purpose for bounties is to award an existing answer

Comment: that's a (mis?) *use* of them, but not their *point*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - no, it's not a misuse, I just uploaded a picture of the bounty popup

Comment: Ah ok, fair enough. Perhaps that should be mentioned I the help page. I'm still not convinced by the question bounty, though; you already (hopefully) *get an answer* when you ask a question, isn't that incentive enough?

Comment: Related question on Meta Stack Exchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135469/bounty-like-facility-for-rewarding-excellent-questions

Comment: [I don't think I have to say anything here, do I?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=29578501#29578501)

Comment: *Stack Overflow has a strong recommendation to use [freehand red circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775), to point at something relevant. Sadly this is a comment and I can't use them right now to point to my comment.*

Comment: @Rizier123 feel free to update the image with a freehand red circle :D

Comment: @jonrsharpe How does rewarding good questions incentivise something useful? I would have thought the answer is obvious.

Comment: @MartinSmith It would encourage users, probably most with not much rep/privileges, to write good questions, since they may get a bounty on it. It will draw attention to good questions and newer users see how good questions can look like.

Comment: I don't think this would be very effective as an incentive for people to write good questions instead of bad questions. It seems like most bad questions come from people who don't really participate enough to know or care whether their question is any good. Those people won't be motivated much by the possibility of getting extra points in a game they aren't playing. The people who would be motivated by that possibility are people who are already participating, and therefore already trying not to write bad questions.

Comment: Just for curiosity, do you have any examples of a question like that? As in, if this feature was implemented tomorrow, what question would you award?

Comment: not so many SO users award bounties on somebody's else posts (related discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314276/make-philanthropic-bounties-a-real-part-of-site-culture, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314442/1506454). just offer a bounty on a high quality question which you like and it is extremely likely the Q get upvotes! (I know that from personal experience on SO); if you are serious in your intentions to promote some good questions, you should give a try, I thunk

Comment: About the "you get answers for asking good questions argument, that is reward enough": Actually more and more often you get answers for asking bad questiosn as well. Or you get comments. In theory this argument may be true, but practically ... not as often as it should.

Comment: When I was in elementary school-Fermat's great theorem of 1636 had not been proven yet. This problem seduced me. I wrote out a lot of pens and wrote down many notebooks, trying my hand to prove it. Fermat's theorem had become one of the greatest mathematical puzzles. Giant bounty in cash was offered. The problem hit the Guinness list as the one with the largest number of unsuccessful proofs. The problem was finally resolved, while I was in high school - 358 years after it was stated. Not only is it sad but also pitiful that SO has no way to appreciate Fermat with a bounty, but a mere upvote.

Answer (score 15):

There have been proposals for rewarding questions with a bounty-like system, and consensus in the answers seemed to be that "upvoting" was enough. But there recently have been [complaints that the question quality is dropping on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow), and I also wondered how to encourage or reward "good questions".

**I don't want to make a definite statement of whether I agree or disagree with the proposal**.

<sup>(^ Edited to emphasize this sentence. Although I only mentioned points that seem to support question bounties, there are also arguments *against* it. See the [answer by Peter Duniho](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319988/3182664) for a more detailed analysis)</sup>

But would like to concur to some of the arguments given in other answers and at other locations. For example, people argued that [answers for bounty questions involves hard research and work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319862/award-a-bounty-for-a-good-question?cb=1#comment327357_319863). Let me point out something with a freehand circle here:

[image: Question research]

As the number of questions increases, it also becomes increasingly hard to ask a "good" question.

<sub>Seriously, whenever you dump some programming-related question into some search engine, the first link is the appropriate answer on stackoverflow. It's nearly boring...</sub>

So there is effort necessary in order to ask a suitable question at all, and a **good** question, in the spirit of the site, *does* involve research effort. This research effort may be rewarded, and it might be appropriate to reward it with more than 5 points.

---

Another argument was that reputation is a measure of trustworthyness. I don't see how this can be an argument against question rewards. If someone asks a question here, the primary goal will in most cases be to receive a good answer. But if he knows how stuff works, he will do his best to *encourage* good answers, and he can do this by properly stating and elaborating the a question - that is, by taking the time to write a **good** question (which is not easy).

So, if someone asks a question in a way that helps to improve the site, then one could "trust" him to some extent.

(At least, there are certainly cases where people flooded the site with 20 poor questions, of which 10 are upvoted by the people who write answers to these poor questions. In these cases, the upvotes for the questions are rather a "reward" offered by those who are happy about finding a question that was so easy that they could answer it. I probably would not "trust" someone with 10*5 points more than someone with 1*50 points...)

---

There recently have been controversial discussions about the [inflation of reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318497/what-exactly-is-artificial-inflation-of-reputation-and-where-is-the-line), and there are certainly arguments *against* such a question bounty system. But I think that one should at least *consider* the option of rewarding **good** questions that stand out against the "do me my homeworks" ones.

Answer (score 5):

I really **don't** like the idea of having a "points transfer" system in Stack Overflow just because "I like that answer, that's why votes are there.

I'm also not a fan of the "Reward existing answer" option, having it would legitimize having its twin: "Reward existing question".

The purpose of [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> If you’ve asked a good question, edited it with status and progress updates, and still are not receiving answers, you can draw attention to your question by placing a bounty on it.

If you start a bounty on a question, it'll eventually get upvotes. I think that rewarding answers differs because usually those answers aren't easy to construct and involve many research efforts and time. Bounty-ing the answer is the way to say "thank you" for answerer who put much efforts on it. If you feel you want to award the question for being good, simply **upvote** it.

We don't want to have a "reputation transfer" system in the sense that some users can simply pass points to others just because they like the quesiton. After all, [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) is:

> a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about

I think it'll be an abused when we'll enable such system.
Bounties are there to encourage answers for questions that didn't draw enough attention, or "hard" questions that requires much efforts. It makes no sense to award the questioner since it might not attract answerers to put more efforts on answering that question.

Comment: My point was that sometimes a question in itself has merit which then leads to great answers as well... but without the question - the knowledge which a good answer provides would have been forever hidden.

Comment: @Danield The upvote seems a good reward on good questions, and those who are really good, will get many of them. Bounty is there in order to draw attention on (probably good) questions.

Comment: I think that besides for just drawing attention, there's also a bounty for rewarding genuinely good answers. Why *shouldn't* there be a bounty for rewarding genuinely good questions?

Comment: @Danield So you're suggesting some kind of "reputation transfer" between users?

Comment: Yes...I don't mind calling it with a different name if 'bounty' seems to be semantically incorrect ;)

Comment: @Danield Interesting. But since reputation seems to reflect someone's *knowledge* on something, transferring points might affect that a bit. Anyway, this is only my opinion :)

Comment: Seems likely to be abused if, in effect, it's a rep transfer system.

Comment: @Paulie_D but how is this different than awarding a bounty on an answer.... you could also call that a rep transfer system? Anyway my point was that sometimes good questions are worth just as much as good answers, so why differentiate between them

Comment: "It makes no sense to award the questioner since it might not attract answerers to put more efforts on answering that question." - just like with answers - we can award them with bounties **after the answer was written**- that's what I'm suggesting for questions.... there may already be answers, good answers... but the fact is that the question was also exemplary - so why not give an option to offer a bounty on the question?

Comment: @Danield Because that's not the purpose of the [bounty-system](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). Again, what people care about is the *solution* of the problem. The system enables improving existing answers, or suggesting new ones, or draw attention to create a one. If you feel you want to award the question for being good, upvote it.

Comment: Your "purpose of bounties" and other objections all seemingly ignore the fact that  "reward an existing answer" is a current option.

Comment: @MartinSmith I don't think that you can simply give answerer points (at least not if you're not the asked). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MarounMaroun you can offer a bounty with "reward existing answer" as the bounty reason and then mark the desired answer with the bounty thus transferring reputation. Why would allowing questions to be the recipient of the award be any more problematic? If the question was not in fact exemplary or otherwise suspicious behaviour was noticed it would be dealt with the same as other bounty abuses.

Comment: @MartinSmith Because asking is not like answering. Usually answers for bounty questions involves hard research and work, bounty is kind of a "tip" for answerer for his efforts.

Comment: And why shouldn't a questioner that asks an interesting well presented question also be able to get such a "tip"?

Comment: @MartinSmith Because you can upvote his question. I guess that now you'll ask "then why not only upvoting the answer" - Because probably the answer wouldn't have been there if no bounty was offered to attract it.

Comment: Again that wouldn't be true for "reward existing answer" by definition the bounty is posted after the answer is given so it is impossible to claim that the answer is only there because of the bounty short of invoking clairvoyance.

Comment: Let's stop using the "reward existing answer" option as a reason for doing anything. That option only exists because people *were* abusing the bounty system to simply tip pre-existing answers, even though that's not what the bounty system was designed for. It was a compromise to at least give other visitors a fair warning that it's very unlikely they'd receive this bounty if they answered the question.

Comment: @animuson The logic there seems a little back to front. The fact that the "reward existing answer" option exists, really does give the impression that it is a valid reason for a bounty. This is actually the first time I have heard otherwise (is what you said some known historical fact) so I believe it has been "backfiring" all this time with people specifically awarding this kind of a bounty and thinking that  that is a valid use case... [even moderators?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254137/703717)

Comment: @Danield It's an "acceptable" use and was added after the fact because we simply have no way to prevent it from happening and, as I said previously, we'd rather users not use other reasons and get people's hopes of receiving it up when the user has already pre-determined who they're going to award it to.

Comment: @animuson  But getting back to the logic behind what you said: How on earth could you know that "people were abusing the bounty system to simply tip pre-existing answers" ?? ... unless of course they left explicit comments relaying that message....in which case the "compromise to give other users a fair warning" wouldn't be necessary

Comment: @animuson I posted a follow-up question with an alternative way to encourage good questions [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320031/703717)

Answer (score 5):

Coincidentally, I was just thinking about this last week. That is, whether it would be a good idea to allow bounties for questions, and whether those bounties should be allowable only for existing questions, or if people should be permitted to even post open bounties to be awarded to questions having specific characteristics (tags, specific programming scenarios, level of difficulty, etc.).

I even considered posting a Meta question about it, to see what others' thoughts were. Ultimately though I didn't, because when I thought about it more, I decided it wasn't a good enough idea to try to argue for.

Don't get me wrong: I agree with the motivation and general sentiment. It's just that ultimately, I feel like allowing bounties to be awarded to questions would have a cost, and would not result in the desired improvement to the site.

What is the cost? Well, just off the top of my head:

1. Developer cost. This is just standard software feature analysis. Every new feature takes time to implement. This time includes not just the basic implementation but also the design work needed to fit it in with the other existing features, the added design work that will be needed to accommodate the feature when other new features are added later, and of course the time to diagnose and fix bugs that are caused by the development work.
   Bottom line: every new feature has a cost. So that feature had better provide some real benefit too.
2. Abuse. No doubt, as soon as you give users another way to transfer reputation points from one account to another, the less scrupulous users will find a way to use that ability to bypass the normal checks and balances intended to maintain quality on the site. Would this result in the immediate collapse of the site? No, of course not. But it would be another bit of drag on the quality of the site, offsetting at least partially whatever expected improvement to quality one would hope for from the feature.
   Note: one argument in favor of this feature has been that rewarding an existing answer is an option on the bounty popup. But it's worth keeping in mind that, [as noted in this comment by moderator animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319862/award-a-bounty-for-a-good-question?cb=1#comment327390_319863), that option exists only as an acknowledgement that while bounties on questions are sometimes abused, there's very little the site can do about that. That option is really more of a "lesser of two evils" compromise than it is an indicator of what's *good* for the site. Indeed, if anything, its presence reminds us that when users can award bounties, there will be abuse of that ability by some users.

So, it would definitely cost something. Both of the above ultimately affect the quality of the site. Abuse obviously does, but even diverting developer resources to the feature would as well, as those are resources that then can't be used to improve the site in other ways.

Are those costs worth it? Would we get a real benefit? Well…

1. Surely there would be *some* increase in the number of high-quality questions. The question is, by how much? The fact is, there is already a theoretically strong incentive to write a good question: **you need an answer to that question!** Given that people still write crappy questions all the time even with that incentive, it seems hard to believe that the average questioner is going to improve their work based on the hypothetical possibility that someone might come along later and award a bounty to their question.
   So maybe we should look at the possibility of having open bounties for questions, i.e. people posting bounties for questions not yet asked, just as we have bounties for answers not yet provided. That seems a little more likely to improve the numbers, by drawing out questions that simply would not even have otherwise been asked. But there's still a fundamental difference between asking and answering: answering is a closed-ended activity, while questioning is an open-ended one. When I write an answer to a good question, I know for sure whether I've done a good job or not. I may not always get rewarded for it, but I can at least compare my results to the goals stated in the question and can know whether I've objectively met those goals.
   But that seems not to work for *questions*. For any given criteria stated for a bounty for a question, there could be any number of possible questions. Never mind that this is the antithesis of the Stack Overflow goal of keeping solicited information (which currently is limited to solicitation of answers, but one can view an open bounty for questions as a solicitation of questions) as focused as possible (hence the "too broad" close reason), it also means that someone trying to win the bounty has very little chance of success. Even if they objectively meet all of the criteria, there's no theoretical limit to the number of other questions that while different would still meet all of those criteria. That competition would render the bounty meaningless; at best, it would be split between multiple questions, and at worst any number of excellent questions would fail to receive any portion of the bounty at all.
   So, while this wasn't even in your proposal, I think open bounties are also unlikely to result in a significant increase in the number of good questions.
2. The bigger problem though is that such a feature would be tantamount to spitting in the wind.
   Stack Overflow is a victim of its own success. It's a great place to find detailed answers to some of the simplest and some of the most difficult programming questions. This draws the attention of the broadest swaths of the programmer population, and frankly there are a lot of people in that population that are average at best. There is a destructive symbiosis between the lazy and the greedy.
   It starts with the lazy. They are too lazy to research their question. Granted, arguably much of Stack Overflow wouldn't even exist if it weren't for this. In spite of the "does not show research" down-vote description, fact is an alarming number of answers I've given on the site are based on *research* I've done. I very often **do not actually know the answer** to the question when I first see it, and yet still successfully answer the question, **by doing research.** I do the research as a way of learning more, and I don't mind it at all (I avoid researching anything that's not interesting to me). But the fact remains that if programmers would just do their own research and do it well, there'd barely be a need for a site like Stack Overflow.
   Still, while it's reasonable to accept that some people are better and/or more motivated to do research, too many questions are worse than just poorly-researched. The person asking has not even bothered to provide a good MCVE, or to format the code in a readable way, or to take care with their use of the English language, or…the list goes on and on. These questions *should* just die a quick death, never to be answered or seen again. Unfortunately, there's the other half of the equation: the greedy.
   These are the people who are, for some reason, inordinately focused on their reputation points. They don't care about the quality of the site. All they care about is getting those points, and they will post answers to any crappy question that they think they remotely have a chance contributing to. They focus on quantity rather than quality, figuring that if they throw enough stuff up there, something will stick. To make matters worse, they up-vote bad questions, making it harder to maintain the quality on that end.
   The lazy and the greedy are feeding each other in a spiral of crappy content that is drowning Stack Overflow and bounties on questions isn't going to elicit nearly enough additional quality questions to offset that.

In other words, it seems to me that the biggest challenge facing Stack Overflow is not the *lack* of good questions. It's the deluge of bad questions, overwhelming the ability of the site community to self-moderate. I will grant that that's a much harder problem to solve, and that awarding bounties to questions *seems* like a good way to at least encourage quality. It's just that doing so has its own cost, and is unlikely to make a dent in the real problems facing the site.

As such, I feel that while well-intentioned, allowing bounties to be awarded to questions isn't a feature that Stack Overflow (or Stack Exchange generally) should be pursuing at the moment).

Comment: Good answer.  In addition, there are a number of options which could be implemented instead which would not have the negatives and would better encourage the results we are looking for.

Comment: Indeed, a good analysis. The relationship between [2. and 3. from this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/3182664) is indeed a problem - particularly one that question bounties could not solve. The vortex of poor/trivial questions and corresponding answers (and the people behind these, upvoting each other) seems to become stronger (my impression - I also still consider myself as a newbie). In that sense, you are right: The cost-benefit ratio of such a question bounty system may not be so great, and the efforts might be better invested elsewhere. (How? That's a different question..)

Comment: I posted a follow-up question with an alternative way to encourage good questions [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320031/703717)