# Can we add our own points to an active bounty anonymously?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I searched [bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty) tag for "add reputation to existing bounty". and found [Make philanthropic bounties a real part of site culture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314276/make-philanthropic-bounties-a-real-part-of-site-culture/314518#314518), though the Question/Answers does not address my question.

Is it possible, or can we make it possible to add our own "points" to an active bounty without

- earning a "badge"
- having any "vote" or input as to how OP awards, or does not award bounty
- other recognition of the users' addition of own points to the active bounty

anonymously?

Comment: What purpose would this really serve?  Do you not want to associate yourself publicly with giving certain bounties?

Comment: @Makoto The purpose would be to reward the correct Answer to the Question. Could not locate a procedure for adding points to an active bounty. Associating oneself is not an issue, though a "reward" or "badge' for doing so is not necessary, at least here; could be an option for that user to choose themselves. That is, the user finds the Question unique, interesting, or estimates would generally add a knowledge base to the site; irrespective if the user who adds point to the bounty is recognized for doing so. "downvote"s are anonymous.

Comment: There's no procedure to add to an active bounty since there's already a bounty in effect.  My gut feeling tells me that this may be in place to prevent rapid boosting of an account; if you two decide to select a user for 500 bounty reputation a piece, then they get a sudden 1K rep.  Is there no reason not to wait until the bounty expires?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "if you two decide to select a user for 500 bounty reputation a piece, then they get a sudden 1K rep"? That would be irrelevant to the user whom added their own points to the active bounty, no? There is no agreement between users. Anonymously. The user determines the Question is of significant value to the general knowledge base, and the user has determined that OP is capable and balanced in their evaluation of requirement described at Question. Once the user adds their own points, they have no input as to the rest. OP awards the bounty, or not, as they decide.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you can't do this, and no, it would not be a good idea.

The purpose of the bounty system is to draw attention and to allow users to reward especially excellent answers. There's no need to allow "add-ons" to an existing bounty. If the initial bounty doesn't draw enough attention, or if you think an answer deserves an even bigger reward, you can always add a new bounty after the first one is awarded or expires.

Allowing anonymous bounties is very problematic, for lots of reasons. People already "game" the bounty system to transfer reputation to their friends and to run [sockpuppets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)). Making any aspect of the bounty system anonymous just encourages more bad behavior. Besides, one of the core values of SO is transparency. We don't allow anonymous *anything*, other than voting.<sup>*</sup> You can use a bogus screen name, of course, but you can't just take random actions around the site - everything is tied to your screen name.

So, no, we don't - and shouldn't - allow anonymous "boosting" of bounties. It ain't broke, so we don't need to fix it, and we certainly shouldn't add more tools for people who want to cheat in various ways.

<sup>* You can request that a post be disassociated from your account, but that requires developer intervention. That's very unusual, in the grand scheme, and requires case-by-case action. It's still not truly anonymous.</sup>

Comment: Was not aware of any "cheating", had not even considered such an act. Do not "cheat" at anything, here, within any field of endeavor; and have no "friends" here. The "anonymous" portion of Question was due to apparent inability to add to an active bounty transparently; either way is same. Are not "upvote" and "downvote" anonymous? A Question, which from users' own estimations, is interesting and is well-researched by OP. The user whom solves Question would get reward based on OP's decision. There is no collusion, here. That is gist of Question.

Comment: @guest271314 Just to be clear, I'm certainly not accusing you of cheating or doing anything nefarious. But you'd be surprised how many people do try to cheat the system, and bounties are one way people do it. Also, you're right about anonymous voting. I edited to correct that. But even with voting, there's a record, and the system allows moderators and staff to catch various kinds of cheating. As for the badge: meh, so the user gets a badge. There are only 4 bounty-related badges, and they're all for the first time you do something. It doesn't hurt anyone that users get those.

Comment: For clarity, the reason for not allowing additions to active bounties - whether "transparently" or "anonymously" - is the potential for abuse by users at stackoverflow? To be specific, "cheaters", or groups of "cheaters"?

Comment: @guest271314 That's one reason. The other big reason is the more philosophical one at the start of my answer: we don't need the ability to "add on" to bounties for bounties to serve their purposes. As for your last question: both, really. We see both kinds of abuse now, and it would be harder to catch them without users flagging weird-looking patterns of behavior. Anonymity (even if moderators could see who did what) would make it harder for users to notice such problems.